# Angular2: Rendering data from Observables

Tags: http, asynchronous, angular, pipe, interpolation

Following interpolation

```
{{ (__responseData | async)?.calculation | json }}
```

outputs following structure

```
[
    {
        "gross": 26.625834,
        "net": 20.425833,
        "tax": 6.2000003
    }
]
```

How can I get gross?

```
{{ (__responseData | async)?.calculation[0].gross }}
```

does not work, and the all the following trys don't work too:

```
{{ (__responseData.calculation[0] | async)?.gross }}
{{ (__responseData.calculation.[0].gross  | async) }}
```

What's the mistake?

EDIT: As workaround I use flatmap (`this.__responseData.flatMap((data: any) => data.calculation);`) but I would like to have an elegant solution,..

Comment: `(__responseData | async)?.calculation[0].gross` should be okay.

Comment: I get the error message: `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null`

Comment: Yeah, getting the same result. Possibly a bug with the array accessor in the template in combination with the async pipe.

Comment: I composed a Plunker for reproducing the bug: http://plnkr.co/edit/d2XJoLsXFXjOH7fSmhbz?p=preview

Comment: Did I accidentally discover a bug?

Comment: Looks like it - you're approach looks right to me. I guess the array accessor get's evaluated before the async pipe runs :(

Comment: Please [open an issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/new), show what you tried and reference the plunker - maybe they have a clue what's going on.

Comment: thank your very much, already done: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10293

Comment: You're going to have to subscribe to the observable in your TS logic, store the latest item somewhere, and then use that in your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the answer from [Alexander](https://github.com/sod) (Angular2-Github-Platform)

You could use *ngFor="let calculation of calculations | async"

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let calculation of calculations | async">
      Gross: {{ calculation.gross }}<br>
      Net: {{ calculation.net }}
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [NgFor]
})
export class App {
  calculations: Observable<{gross:number; net:number}[]>;

  constructor(private _http: Http) {
    this.calculations = this._http.get("./data.json")
                            .map(res => res.json().calculation)
  }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/3ze70dYycQxNyXA286mX?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Is it not a bug. It is because you are doing elvis operator (`?.`) on the `calculation`. In case the service is not done yet, you'll get `null` out of that first part `(__responseData | async)?.calculation`, then you immediately get the first element out of a null value, and that's when the error happens.

To avoid exception in this case, you have to make sure `(__responseData | async)?.calculation` is not null before trying to go further down. As far as I know, we do not have `?[i]` operator for array, so I suggest you go with a helper method.

I've done that in this plunker for your reference: http://plnkr.co/edit/pkZW9lQfk1f5hKczKtim?p=preview

Or this: http://plnkr.co/edit/ybvEvAr4t7dUvmAfFf3q?p=preview

Comment: I understand this approach but you can not write every time a pipe for every data structure or for its elements. How can I ouput "gross" wihout additional pipes or/and elvis operator? Is there an another way?

Comment: It is one of the ways to solve the issue. However I believe that manipulating data is not the job of templates (view), but the Components (controller) and Services. It is believed to be a good practice if in your call to the service (in your component), you add in a `map` function to refine the return data before serving it to template.

Comment: thank you but I already use flatmap as workaround (see my edited question above) I need a solution at the rendering side: I always want to able to select, which element I want to show/render,..